# Calling a derived function (not overridden) from a base class pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

Ii'm trying to figure out how to call a derived class-only method from a base class pointer without declaring it `virtual` in both base and derived class.

My code is:

ContoBancario.h

```
#ifndef BANCARIO_H
#define BANCARIO_H


class ContoBancario{


private:
        double saldo;

public:
        ContoBancario(double);
        void setSaldo(double);
        double getSaldo();

        virtual void deposita (double);
        virtual void ritira (double);


};

#endif
```

ContoVincolato.h

```
#ifndef VINCOLATO_H
#define VINCOLATO_H


#include "ContoBancario.h"

class ContoVincolato:public ContoBancario {

private:

    double tasso;

public:

    ContoVincolato(double,double);
    double calcolaInteresse ();


};


#endif
```

ContoCorrente.h

```
#ifndef CORRENTE_H
#define CORRENTE_H

#include "ContoBancario.h"

class ContoCorrente : public ContoBancario {

private:
    double costoOp;

public:
    ContoCorrente(double,double);
    void setCostoOp(double);



    virtual void deposita(double);
    virtual void ritira(double);




};




#endif
```

now, in my main file i've created a vector of pointer to the base class, that point to instances of 2 classes:

```
ContoVincolato c1(2500, .05);

ContoCorrente c2 (1500, 1.5);


vector <ContoBancario *> conti(2);
conti[0]=&c1;
conti[1]=&c2;
```

so I get access to redefined virtual function just using pointers with

```
for (size_t i=0;i<conti.size();i++){

    conti[i]->ritira(500);
    conti[i]->deposita(350);
}
```

But: I can't figure out how to use the method i didn't override in ContoVincolato.h, `conti[0]->calcolaInteresse();` gives compiler error:

class ContoBancario has no member named 'calcolaInteresse'.

How could I solve this?

Comment: You solve this by designing your classes correctly, instead of trying to find a way to hack around a bad class design.

Comment: That's not the only compiler error. There is no `ritira` method exposed from `ContoBancario` either, nor is there a `deposita` method. There *is* a `deposit` method, so perhaps the latter is a simple typo (something that continually confounds me in circumstances where cutting/pasting should be done, rather than inline code-authoring in a question body).

Comment: The class design is given, can t change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you won't reconsider your class design, the way to do this is with `dynamic_cast`:

```
ContoCorrente *contoC = dynamic_cast<ContoCorrente *>(conti[0]);
if (contoC != nullptr)
{
    val = contoC->calcolaInteresse();
}
```

This requires that RTTI (Run Time Type Information) is enabled in your compiler.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast